# Replace columns with multi level columns based on lookup on Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, hierarchical-data

How can I replace this single column heading:

```
    foo bar
0   0   0
1   0   0
```

To get these multi level columns:

```
    A   B
    a   b
0   0   0
1   0   0
```

Based on this dataframe mapping

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   foo     a       A
1   bar     b       B
2   baz     c       C
```

I am trying a list comprehension trying to create a new multi level column index but doesn't seem to be working...I have a feeling there is a more pythonic way to achieve this nonetheless

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[0,0],
                    'bar':[0,0]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['foo','bar','baz'],
                    'col2':['A','B','C'],
                    'col3':['a','b','c']})

df1.columns = [(df2.loc[df2['col1']==i,'col2'], df2.loc[df2['col1']==i,'col3']) for i in df1.columns]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform df2 to a Series of tuples and map it to the columns:

```
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(df2.set_index('col1').apply(tuple, axis=1))
```

output:

```
   A  B
   a  b
0  0  0
1  0  0
```

Comment: Is there a way to flip the column headings so ['A','B'] is on bottom?

Comment: `df1.swaplevel(axis=1)`

Comment: i'm getting this error when working with my data set, even though it seems like everything is string: TypeError: Expected tuple, got float

Comment: ok i found the problem. my column label names have commas in them which gave them different length tuples, remove the commas in the column names and everything is good